# finfo_file() returns wrong mime type for some images?

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types, file-type

I allow image uploads on my website and need to get the file types of uploaded files so that I can check to see if the type is whitelisted and allowed to be uploaded.

I've been doing this by using `finfo_file()`, but it doesn't seem to work in all cases. Here's my code:

```
// get the mime type
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime  = finfo_file($finfo, $filePath);
echo $mime;
```

http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41q8koaxM0L.jpg

Try running the above code on the image above and it will say the MIME type is `application/octet-stream` when it is clearly a JPG file.

Why is `finfo_file()` not working with the test image? How can I fix whatever the problem is so that I can accurately get the file type?

Comment: Where'd you download the image from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could also use `exif_imagetype()` in conjunction to `image_type_to_mime_type()`. Example:

```
function get_mime($url) {
    $image_type = exif_imagetype($url);
    return image_type_to_mime_type($image_type);
}

echo get_mime('http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41q8koaxM0L.jpg'); // image/jpeg
```